# JAX-RS/Jersey: java.lang.ClassCastException - cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have application separated to frontend and backend modules which communicate through restfull webservice. Unfortunately, something goes wrong in this code and I get from Backend part:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rrd.ecomdd.data.SharedFile cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
```

Frontend snippet:

```
@Override
public void share(Set<SharedFile> fileSet) {
    apiTarget.path(ApiConstant.FILESERVICE)
            .path(ApiConstant.FILESERVICE_SHARE)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.withCharset("UTF-8"))
            .post(Entity.entity(fileSet.toArray(new SharedFile[0]), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.withCharset("UTF-8")), new GenericType<Set<SharedFile>>() {
            });
}
```

Backend snippet

```
@POST
@Path(ApiConstant.FILESERVICE_SHARE)
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public List<SharedFile> share(SharedFile[] sharedList) {
    for (SharedFile s : sharedList) {
        fileService.share(s);
    }
    return Arrays.asList(sharedList);
}
```

SharedFile class:

```
public class SharedFile {

  private Long id;
  private User user;
  private ManagedFile file;
  private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

  public SharedFile(User user, ManagedFile file) {
    this.user = user;
    this.file = file;
  }

  public SharedFile() {
  }
  //getters, setters, equals and hashcode below

}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to annotate the class and its attributes as mentioned here:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SharedFile {

  @XmlElement
  private Long id;

  @XmlElement
  private User user;

  @XmlElement
  private ManagedFile file;
```

Follow this for more: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html